# Give a parameter to a function by geting from URL in Javascprit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, get

Hi I have three function for a chess piece moving to another place. First of all I want to explain what I want to do and after will explain my method.If any diffirent idea please also tell me.

**Purpose:**
Imagine that a chess board and ı want move X to A means that h2 to h4

a b c d e f g h

1* * * * * * * *

2* * * * * * * X

3* * * * * * * *

4* * * * * * * A

5* * * * * * * *

6* * * * * * * *

7* * * * * * * *

8* * * * * * * *

and it works on html and js.

I have an url like chess/index.html# and  I can drag and drop pieces by click.
I also want to pieces and its moves on link as a parameter and when I give the parameters like

eg:
"piece=white_pawn&position=h4"
It should also move as I handled drag and drop
when I write chess.html#piece=white_pawn&position=h4 it should move to h4

I have three functions for it and I will paste them.

**Functions:**

1-The function is move function.

```
function build_move(board, from, to, flags, promotion) {
        var move = {
            color: turn,
            from: from,
            to: to,
            flags: flags,
            piece: board[from].type
        };

        if (promotion) {
            move.flags |= BITS.PROMOTION;
            move.promotion = promotion;
        }

        if (board[to]) {
            move.captured = board[to].type;
        } else if (flags & BITS.EP_CAPTURE) {
            move.captured = PAWN;
        }
         var url=window.location.hash;
       window.history.pushState(move,'',url);
       move_by_link(window.location.search);
    }
```

I created a var ***moving*** and I considered it to move_by_link() function.

2-Move by link:
This is for moving by url parameters from change url

```
 function move_by_link(move)
    {
       

         const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(url);

        var move = {
            color: urlParams.get('color'),
            from: urlParams.get('from'),
            to: urlParams.get('to'),
            flags: urlParams.get('flags'),
            piece: urlParams.get('piece')
        };


        
        return move ;
      


    }
```

I tried to handle like that but it doesn't work any diffirent idea or solution for this code?

Thanks...

Comment: `it returns "[object%20object]"` for which key of the move object does it do that?  Are you sure you want a &piecemove parameter for each member of the move object?  It doesn't look the same as `piece=white_pawn&position=h4` for example.

Comment: yeah I want to do this logic piece=white_pawn&position=h4 but it is not important I write the code 
 function ChangeURL(move)
    {
        
        var s="";
        for (var key in move)
        {
          s+="&piecemove="+String(move[key]);
        }
        var url=""+s;
        return url;

    }     the param names are not important the important is parameter should pass tp functipn and returns move I hope it is clear sorry for the complicated example I just want parameters should go on move_by_link function

Comment: You will need to learn about `history.pushState()` and how to use `URLSearchParams()` API. Setting window.location is going to reload page but pushState() won't

Comment: @charlietfl I tried to push state and it gives me on link undefined do you have any sıolution for it

Comment: Not sure how you have implemented it. You could ask a different question and include what you tried. Before that I would study some tutorials for it

Comment: @charlietfl  I edited the code last version can you check it? I am appriciate to you.